# Bokeh grouped bar chart, changing data presented

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, bokeh

I'm experimenting with the grouped bar chart example for Bokeh using Pandas shown below.  I am trying to see if I can get it to display the data differently for example I wanted the bar graph to show a count of the rows that meet each group.  I tried that by replacing instances of 'mpg_mean' to 'mpg_count' but just got an invalid column error.   I also experimented with having the graph show a sum by again using 'mpg_sum' with the same error.  I'm assuming the calculation for the 'mpg_mean' is occurring in the groupby but how do I get it to display the count or the sum?  It's definitely not clear in this example where any calculations are happening.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral5
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg_clean as df
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

output_file("bar_pandas_groupby_nested.html")

df.cyl = df.cyl.astype(str)
df.yr = df.yr.astype(str)

group = df.groupby(by=['cyl', 'mfr'])

index_cmap = factor_cmap('cyl_mfr', palette=Spectral5, factors=sorted(df.cyl.unique()), end=1)

p = figure(width=800, height=300, title="Mean MPG by # cylinders and manufacturer",
           x_range=group, toolbar_location=None, tooltips=[("MPG", "@mpg_mean"), ("Cyl, Mfr", "@cyl_mfr")])

p.vbar(x='cyl_mfr', top='mpg_mean', width=1, source=group,
       line_color="white", fill_color=index_cmap, )

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.05
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Manufacturer grouped by # Cylinders"
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.2
p.outline_line_color = None

show(p)
```

Comment: You are performing `df.groupby(by=['cyl', 'mfr'])` which returns a `DataFrameGroupBy` a not a `DataFrame`. I am pretty sure that this is not a valid source for a bokeh chart. By the way, `df.groupby(by=['cyl', 'mfr'])` is normaly followed by an aggregataion function like `df.groupby(by=['cyl', 'mfr']).mean()` or  `df.groupby(by=['cyl', 'mfr']).count()` which will return a DataFrame. Hope this helps.

Comment: mosc9575 is right. make your groupdata dataframe.

Comment: You can use a DataFrameGroupBy as a bokeh chart input,  the code I pasted above is an example code provided by Bokeh and works as shown but it looks like the mean is the only calculated value in the GroupBy data set as nothing else works.  I've tried editing it so it's `group = df.groupby(by=['cyl', 'mfr']).count()` and changing the chart to `p.vbar(x='cyl_mfr', top='mpg', width=1, source=group, line_color="white", fill_color=index_cmap, )` but that just gives me an error.